# How to implement collapsible menus in App Inventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

I want to implement a JQuery mobile expandable list or an accordion in my road safety app that houses numerous motorcycling and car tips. I was told that I could import the html from  file:///mnt/sdcard/AppInventor/assets/test.html using the `WebViewer` component but I am currently clueless.
My questions are:

1. **How do I go about the accordion code using JQuery mobile?**
2. **How do I use the WebViewer component to load the accordion screen?**

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I managed to get the jQuery Mobile Docs source code snippets. Any further information on it's implementation would be more than appreciated though!

Edit 2: I know the file paths to the screens as this works in development
file:///mnt/sdcard/AppInventor/assets/test.html
because App Inventor puts the file in an assets folder when it loads

and this works from the apk
file:///android_asset/test.html

**How do I bundle this html page with the assets?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find loads of [App Inventor examples using HTML/JavaScript here](http://puravidaapps.com/tutorials.php#html)

If you need to access your html page with input parameters, you will have to download the html file from somewhere to your sd card because of an [Android bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535), else you can upload it to the assets of your project.